# Image Processing: Low quality re-implementation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new in Image Processing with MATLAB. I am trying to re-implement the paper "Single Image Haze Removal Using Dark Channel Prior" (DCP) by He et. al..

Although the haze-free images are quite good in visibility, but the PSNR and SSIM value are not good. Comparing to [other benchmark](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04143), their PSNR and SSIM results could reach 16.62 and 0.8179, respectively. My implementation reaches only 7.07 and 0.002.

I have no idea to overcome this and look for some suggestions.

**[Update] Solved by using `im2uint8()` instead of `uint8()`**

```
image = imread(imagePath);

% dehaze
patch_size = 15;
omega = 0.95;
r = 60;
eps = 0.001;
tx = 0.1;
haze_free = dcp_guidedfilter(image, patch_size, omega, r, eps, tx, true);

% measure quality
haze_free = im2uint8(haze_free);
[peaksnr, snr] = psnr(haze_free, image);
[ssimval,ssimmap] = ssim(haze_free, image);
```

Comment: SSIM is 0.002? That means that your image looks nothing at all like what you're comparing against. You should be able to look at the image and the expected result, and see how they are different. Maybe you're comparing against the wrong image?

Comment: Maybe the other benchmark is wrong, who knows ?

Comment: as it stands, this question isn't debuggable. you've given nothing concrete to discuss. please review [mre].

Comment: Some code to show your effort and reproducing your error would be nice.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I checked my double-type `haze_free` output image after executing `haze_free = uint8(haze_free)` and it was completely black. It should be converted using `im2uint8(haze_free)` instead. Now the PSNR and SSIM value are 17.81 and 0.76 respectively.